# Exporting Excel file to PDF - getting stuck trying to close Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, com-interop, office-interop

I have a function that takes a url to an Excel file, and then exports it as a pdf:

```
public static void ExportFromExcel(string url)
{
    // Create COM Objects
    Application excelApplication = new Application();
    Workbook excelWorkbook = 
        excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(url));

    try
    {
        // Call Excel's native export function
        excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(
            XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, 
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(url.Replace(".xlsx", ".pdf")));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the workbook, quit Excel, and clean up regardless of the results
        excelWorkbook.Close();    // HANGS AND FAILS HERE
        excelApplication.Quit();

        excelApplication = null;
        excelWorkbook = null;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is creating an Excel file, and then immediately creating a pdf from that file:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath)))
{
    byte[] data = pck.GetAsByteArray();
    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

Pdf.ExportFromExcel(filePath);
```

It will create the Excel file just fine, and it will also create the pdf. But the page hangs for a long time, and then gives me the error at `excelWorkbook.Close();` in my pdf code:

> **The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)**

The files actually get created though. But if I go to the file directory, there is a temporary Excel file as well (my Excel filename with the `~$` in front of it).

If I try and delete my Excel file, I get an error saying the file is being used by another process, and I can't delete my Excel file until I kill the EXCEL.EXE in the Task Manager.

So for some reason, my Excel file won't close after it finishes creating the pdf. Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Interop on the server (including ASP.NET/IIS!) is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2**

Since Windows Vista MS introduced several security-related measures which prevent a Windows Service (like ASP.NET on IIS) from doing "desktop-like" things (accessing printers, accessing network shares etc.)... which means you would have to circumvent several security measures to get it to work (NOT recommended!).

To deal with Excel files without any need for Office etc. in a server-scenario there are several options (free and commercial) out there:

I can recommend [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) - both come with PDF export functionality... didn't try [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) but hear+read lots of good things about it...

Free options (though for the newer xlsx format only, not sure whether they support PDF export!) are for example  [OpenXML 2 from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't afford to pay for those products, and the free options don't offer support for PDF export. Actually, here's a post where an MSFT says to use interop capabilities (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/oxmlsdk/thread/26d9879a-6c1f-4a71-8dde-d6a1d9b0b110).

Everywhere else I've looked also says to just use interop as well.

So I'm getting conflicted opinions all over the place. I'd rather not use interop - do you know of any other way I can do this?

Comment: @Steven sorry, I don't know of any other ways. Interop is DEFINETELY NOT supported with ASP.NET (see the first link in my answer - it is an official MSFT link from their knowledge base)...

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up using itextsharp to create the pdf

Answer (score 1):

I know that this "offically" has been answered as "not supported".  That said, I ran into this same issue.

The actual exception is kind of a red herring.  The real issue is Permissions.

You can either set your web service to run under the identity of a user with adequate permissions (not always a good idea) OR you can go into DCOMCNFG and alter the permissions of the Excel app so that your System user has the right access.

I hope that this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use following code to export excel file to pdf:**

```
// Saving an XLS file in Aspose.Pdf xml format
Workbook wb = new Workbook();
wb.Open("C:\\book1.xls);
wb.Save("C:\\xls2pdf.xml", FileFormatType.AsposePdf);

// Converting XLS file to PDF through Aspose.Pdf using Aspose.Pdf xml file as a medium
Aspose.Pdf.Pdf pdf = new Aspose.Pdf.Pdf();
pdf.BindXML("c:\\xls2pdf.xml", null);
pdf.Save("C:\\xls2pdf.pdf");


You can download Aspose.pdf from the following link
http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/category1184.aspx

You can download Aspose.cells from the following link
http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/category1184.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install The 2007 Microsoft Office Suite Service Pack 3 (SP3)
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27838
2. Install 2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7

**Mandatory :** Set **Microsoft XPS Document Writer** as default printer in server. 
Because **ExportAsFixedFormat** function executes **Microsoft XPS Document Writer** to convert Excel to PDF.

This is working for me.